# Join a modified split array with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm joining a list originally split on "/" where the last token was changed. All I have to do is remove brackets ([]) in the **last** token, then rebuild the list with "/".

```
trimOnLastToken : function(str) {

   // str comes in as:  test1/test2/test3[0]

   var tokens = str.split("/");
   // In-Place modification of the last token: does not work
   alert('Tokens = ' + tokens);
   tokens[tokens.length-1].replace(/\[.*\]/g, '');
   alert('Tokens AFTER = ' + tokens);
   var result = tokens.join("/");
   return result;
```

}

The tokens are the same before and after, so the list is unchanged. Do I need to re-build from 0..n-1 and then manually append a new var with a modified last token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strings are immutable, you need to re-assign the value:

```js
var trimOnLastToken = function(str) {

   // str comes in as:  test1/test2/test3[0]

   var tokens = str.split("/");
   // In-Place modification of the last token: does not work
   alert('Tokens = ' + tokens);
   tokens[tokens.length-1] = tokens[tokens.length-1].replace(/\[.*\]/g, '');
   alert('Tokens AFTER = ' + tokens);
   var result = tokens.join("/");
   return result;
}

alert(trimOnLastToken("test1/test2/test3[0]"));
```